# @Html.BeginForm Post value from dropdown Change event instead of a submit button

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, form-submit

I am trying to implement a 'refine' option within my MVC project.

At the top of my view, I have something like

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                       ______                    |
|               SELECT:| 1 |▼||                   |
|                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Where user can select a number from a drop down list.

However, in order to post this, it requires a 'submit button':

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
|                       ______                    |
|               SELECT:| 1 |▼||      [GO]         |
|                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Is there any way of removing this 'GO' button so that it automatically sends this value to the controller when i select a value from the dropdown?

## VIEW

```
<a style="font-size:large;font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:50%"> 
Select:@Html.DropDownList("Number") <input type="submit" value="GO" id="subBtn" /></a>
```

## CONTROLLER

```
 public ActionResult Index(string Number)
 {

  if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Number))
        var bays = db.Bays.Include(b => b.Product);
        {
            int t = Convert.ToInt32(Number);
           bays = bays.Where(x => x.ID == t);  
        }

  var Number = new List<int>();

  var choice = from x in db.Bays
                orderby x.ID
                select x.ID;

  Number.AddRange(choice.Distinct());

  ViewBag.Number = new SelectList(Number); //populates list
  return View(bays.ToList());
  }
```

---

So basically, my query is 'can the drop down also work as the 'submit' on a selection change, and if so, how to implement this?'

Comment: You can do it with javascript/jquery (handle the dropdown's change event and submit the form)

Comment: I really don't know either @StephenMuecke - i've avoided them for yonks *because* they're so unreliable- one small bug and the website's rendered useless :( - plus i prefer working server side over client any day, as well as [stuff like this](http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/07/10-very-good-reasons-to-stop-using-javascript/)

Comment: A bug in your server code _"and the website's rendered useless"_ too! If your developing websites, learn javascript.

Comment: debugging server code is ***much*** easier, you've got to admit! And then since this is a corporate/admin site to view stock levels/etc, making a site 'fancy' isn't really part of the spec.

Comment: Its not that hard. [Debugging javascript](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging). And its often about performance not just _making a site 'fancy'_

Comment: does javascript not reduce performance since it ***is*** executed on client side?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.
1. Create a form with the action you want to handle the post and keep your dropdown inside the form.
2. Set the id for the dropdown say for example 'productCounter'.
3. Create a jquery function based on the dropdown onchange event.
4. In that function trigger the form submit action.

```
$("#productCounter").change(function(){
    $("form[0]").submit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should alter your code as follows:

```
@Request.ServerVariables["REQUEST_METHOD"]
<hr />

@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
<a style="font-size:large;font-weight:bold; padding-bottom:50%"> 
Select: @Html.DropDownList("Number", null, null, new { onchange="document.forms[0].submit();" })</a>
}
```

I added the @Request.ServerVariables["REQUEST_METHOD"] bit only to see that the page is posted once you change the select option.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC, then you sure have to learn some javascript/jQuery skills. As DropDownList is simply razor syntax and it is rendered as HTML in client side, you have to use ajax to send the data from client to the server.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $(document).on("change", "#number", function () {
            var form = $("#YourFormName"); //post your form for all the input of form
            //var number=$(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("Index")',
                data: form.serialize(), // data:{Number:number}, if you want to send  value of dropdownlist only
                success: function () {
                    //logic for success
                },
                error: {
                    //logic for error
                    //logger
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: MVC doesn't **require** javascript/jquery skills, but may be useful. As for your answer, OP does not ***have to use*** ajax.

Answer (score 0):

this is the example I used

View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
            {
                @Html.DropDownList("month", null, new
            {
                onchange = @"submit();"
            })}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(int month)
{
ViewBag.month= new SelectList(new SelectList(
      Enumerable.Range(1, 12)
          .Select(r => new
          {
              Text = new DateTime(1, r, 1).ToString("MM"),
              Value = r.ToString()
          }),
      "Value", "Text", "").ToList(), "Value", "Text", month.ToString());
return View();
    }
```